# Packer.nvim: error running config for XXXX: attempt to call a nil value

Tags: lua, neovim

I have updated neovim to the latest version in the stable ppa (0.7.2)

However, I get some

```
Packer.nvim: error running config for toggleterm.nvim: attempt to call a nil value
Packer.nvim: error running config for nvim-cmp: attempt to call a nil value
...
```

I am not sure what could cause an error like this and how to debug it.

My plugins.lua (removing some unrelated plugins looks as follows)

```
local fn = vim.fn

-- Automatically install packer
local install_path = fn.stdpath "data" .. "/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim"
if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
  PACKER_BOOTSTRAP = fn.system {
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--depth",
    "1",
    "https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim",
    install_path,
  }
  print "Installing packer close and reopen Neovim..."
  vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
end

-- Autocommand that reloads neovim whenever you save the plugins.lua file
vim.cmd [[
  augroup packer_user_config
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost plugins.lua source <afile> | PackerSync
  augroup end
]]

-- Use a protected call so we don't error out on first use
local status_ok, packer = pcall(require, "packer")
if not status_ok then
  return
end

-- Have packer use a popup window
packer.init {
  display = {
    open_fn = function()
      return require("packer.util").float { border = "rounded" }
    end,
  },
}

-- Install your plugins here
return packer.startup(function(use)
  -- My plugins here
  use "wbthomason/packer.nvim" -- Have packer manage itself
  use "nvim-lua/popup.nvim" -- An implementation of the Popup API from vim in Neovim
  use "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" -- Useful lua functions used by lots of plugins
  use {"akinsho/toggleterm.nvim", tag = 'v2.*', config = function()
       require("toggleterm").setup()
  end}

  -- complete plugins
  use {'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp', config = function() require('cmp')
        end,
  }
    -- The completion plugin
  use "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer" -- buffer completions
  use "hrsh7th/cmp-path" -- path completions
  use "hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline" -- cmdline completions
  use "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp" -- lsp completions

  -- snippets
  use {"L3MON4D3/LuaSnip", --snippet engine
    after = 'nvim-cmp',
    config = function() require('luasnip.snippets') end,
  }
  use "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip" -- snippet completions
  use "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets" -- a bunch of snippets to use

  -- Telescope
  use "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim"

  -- Treesitter
  use {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    run = ":TSUpdate"
  }

  -- Automatically set up your configuration after cloning packer.nvim
  -- Put this at the end after all plugins
  if PACKER_BOOTSTRAP then
    require("packer").sync()
  end
end)
```

and for toggleterm.lua as follows

```
local status_ok, toggleterm = pcall(require, "toggleterm")
if not status_ok then
  print("Toggleterm status not OK")
    return
end

toggleterm.setup({
    size = 20,
    open_mapping = [[<c-\>]],
    hide_numbers = true,
    shade_filetypes = {},
    shade_terminals = true,
    shading_factor = 2,
    start_in_insert = true,
    insert_mappings = true,
    persist_size = true,
    direction = "float",
    close_on_exit = true,
    shell = vim.o.shell,
    float_opts = {
        border = "curved",
        winblend = 0,
        highlights = {
            border = "Normal",
            background = "Normal",
        },
    },
})

function _G.set_terminal_keymaps()
  local opts = {noremap = true}
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 't', '<esc>', [[<C-\><C-n>]], opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 't', 'jk', [[<C-\><C-n>]], opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 't', '<C-h>', [[<C-\><C-n><C-W>h]], opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 't', '<C-j>', [[<C-\><C-n><C-W>j]], opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 't', '<C-k>', [[<C-\><C-n><C-W>k]], opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, 't', '<C-l>', [[<C-\><C-n><C-W>l]], opts)
end

vim.cmd('autocmd! TermOpen term://* lua set_terminal_keymaps()')

local Terminal = require("toggleterm.terminal").Terminal

local node = Terminal:new({ cmd = "node", hidden = true })

function _NODE_TOGGLE()
    node:toggle()
end

local ncdu = Terminal:new({ cmd = "ncdu", hidden = true })

function _NCDU_TOGGLE()
    ncdu:toggle()
end

local htop = Terminal:new({ cmd = "htop", hidden = true })

function _HTOP_TOGGLE()
    htop:toggle()
end

local python = Terminal:new({ cmd = "python", hidden = true })

function _PYTHON_TOGGLE()
    python:toggle()
end
```

Comment: You should at least provide your config of packer.nvim for these two plugins, otherwise, how would you suppose others to know your config magically :) ? At stackoverflow, always provide as detailed and relevant info as possible to increase your chance of getting anwsered.

Answer (score 1):

`:PackerUpdate` (from inside nvim) fixed the issue for me.